# Need to give each value in columns with the vaue

Tags: python, pandas

as you seen we have four columns. what i need  is whenever business_size come give him value on WoE
is there easy it way to replace it witout using map?

## Mapping to replace each categrcal with their WOE

```
BUSINESS_Size_WOE={'Very Small':-0.681051,
                       'Micro':-0.276262,
                       'Small and Medium':-0.039605,
                       'Larger Taxpayer':0.534305,
                       'Very Larger ':0.605551
} 

train['BUSINESS_Size_WOE'] = train.BUSINESS_Size.map(BUSINESS_Size_WOE).apply(pd.to_numeric).astype(float)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use replace()

```
train['BUSINESS_Size_WOE'] = train.BUSINESS_Size.replace(BUSINESS_Size_WOE).apply(pd.to_numeric).astype(float)
```

beware of the space in your code after Very Larger in your dictionary
i advise you to declare your dictionary without it to match the name in your dataframe like this :

```
BUSINESS_Size_WOE={'Very Small':-0.681051,
                       'Micro':-0.276262,
                       'Small and Medium':-0.039605,
                       'Larger Taxpayer':0.534305,
                       'Very Larger':0.605551
}
```

Comment: i need to replace it without copy and paste the value of WoE columns

Comment: can you explain more please !

Comment: for example if i want to replace any value in the BUSINESS_Size column for instance Very Small withtheir value in the column Woe is -0.681051 etc for now i am using  like this below code ``` BUSINESS_Size_WOE={'Very Small':-0.681051,
                       'Micro':-0.276262,
                       'Small and Medium':-0.039605,
                       'Larger Taxpayer':0.534305,
                       'Very Larger':0.605551
}```